# How to write query to get names of primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure :

```
Location
--------------
location_id   name
1            Location1
2            Location2
3            Location3

Tour_available
--------------
tour_available_id     from_location    to_location
1                         2               3
2                         1               2 
3                         2               1
```

In above table from_location and to_location are foreign_keys(Which is primary key in Location table)

I want output as:

```
Expected output
--------------
from_location    to_location
Location2         Location3
Location1         Location2
Location2         Location1
```

Comment: Join location twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select FL.name as frm_location, TL.name as t_location 
  from Tour_available as TA INNER JOIN Location as FL ON (FL.location_id = TA.from_location) 
    INNER JOIN Location as TL ON (TL.location_id = TA.to_location);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). The idea is to take the `tour_available` table and then for each item on the `from_location` query the `location` table using a join. Repeat that in the same query for the `to_location`. This is a **n:m relation**.

In your situation this would be:

```
SELECT
  f.name as from_location, -- JUST RENAME OUR COLUMNS TO NICER NAMES
  t.name as to_location
FROM
  tour_available ta,
  location f,              -- select the table for our "from_location"
                           -- without specifying anything this will
                           -- be treated as a an INNER JOIN. Every location
                           -- in tour_available must match an entry in location.
  location t               -- select the table for our "to_location"
WHERE
  ta.from_location == f.location_id -- from_location selects entry in f
AND ta.to_location == t.location_id -- to_location selects entry in t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
l1.name as "from_location",
l2.name as "to_location"
from Tour_available ta
join Location l1 on l1.location_id = ta.from_location 
join Location l2 on l2.location_id = ta.to_location
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.name as from_location,C.name as to_location
From Location A inner join [dbo].[Tour_available] B
On A.location_id=B.from_location
Inner Join
Location C
On C.location_id=B.to_location
```